# как отбитмапить объект в SFML

Tags: c++, sfml

Скажите, а есть ли возможность каким-то образом грабить(копировать) изображения в массивы ?
мне надо держать такую карту. С фигурами типа прямоугольник таких проблем нет, а вот скажем напишу я текст какой по средствам sf::Text как мне все его точки скопировать в массив ???

Comment: Это называется render to texture.

Comment: @user7860670 спасибо. поковыряю

Comment: @user7860670 Привет. ну вот я сделал примерно вот так :  https://www.online-cpp.com/K5h4QLOAGw а как мне загнать область 500x500 в массив ???